# Save/Load Variables in js

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage, p5.js

I'm trying to create a save/load function for my game in js, but I have basically no idea with how to go through with doing this. I can save variables to a JSON file or LocalStorage, but I don't know how to load them back into the program. I'm also pretty sure I'm exporting variables the wrong way as well. Any help?

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: Right now this question is pretty broad. Can you start by googling something like "JavaScript load from local storage"? What results do you see?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: Take a look at the documentation here https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Loading-external-files:-AJAX,-XML,-JSON It should at least allow you to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I use JSON format to store and read data (of any type).

To save data (using key `gamedata` as example):

```
   var myData = {
      name: 'David',
      score: 10
   }

   localStorage.setItem('gamedata', JSON.stringify(myData));
```

** without JSON.stringify, you data will be saved as string `[Object object]`

To retrieve the data back:

```
   var savedData = localStorage.getItem('gamedata');  // savedData is string
   var myData = JSON.parse(savedData); // parse JSON string to java object
```

Answer (score 0):

setup a bin on [www.myJSON.com](http://www.myJSON.com). p5 has built in functionality for ajax requests such as [loadJSON](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadJSON). that way it's not in local storage and you can access your data if you have it on github. I know your struggle, I used to deal with this sort of issue myself before I found [myJSON](http://www.myJSON.com)